# PHPDoc Tag to supress warnings about dynamic functions-calls

Tags: php, cakephp, dynamic, phpstorm, phpdoc

we have a cakePHP Project and use a `Path`-class for dynamic linkcreations.

Example:

```
$this->redirect(Path::action_my_controller_path($id));
```

Would redirect to the action `action` of the `MyController`-class and handle the parameter `$id`.

So now my IDE (PHPStorm) is always complaining about the missing functions in `Path`-class as there is no specified `action_my_controller_path($id)`-function.

Does anyone know about an PHP-Doc annotation to suppress this messages?

edit:
After "speaking" with LazyOne via comments I've added the following PHPDoc in the `Path`-class, as described in his link ( [phpDocumentor](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#811-method) ):

```
 /**
 *
 * @method array|string callStatic(string $name, string $args)
 */

class Path extends Object
```

But I still get the Warning when calling my `Path`-class (see example above). The autogenerated phpDoc (from my IDE) for this method is is

```
/**
 * @param $name
 * @param $args
 *
 * @return array|string
 */
public static function __callStatic($name, $args){
```

If I write

```
 /**
 *
 * @method array|string __callStatic(string $name, string $args)
 */

class Path extends Object
```

I get an `Method with same name already defiend in class`-error :/

edit2: Full `Path`-class

```
<?php

/**
 * Zentrale Klasse fuer die Pfade, wobei jede Methode eines der akzeptierten
 * Formate von Router#url zurueckgibt, damit Router#url diese dann in eine
 * URL (als String) umwandeln kann.
 *
 * h3. Benutzung im View:
 *
 * <pre>
 *   $url = Path::alliances_path();
 *   $Html->link($url);
 * </pre>
 *
 *
 * h3. Konventionen (ueber __callStatic umgesetzt):
 *
 * <pre>
 * Semantische URL          <- Methoden Aufruf
 * -----------------------------------------------------------
 * /alliances               <- Path::alliances_path()
 * /alliances/add           <- Path::new_alliance_path()
 * /alliances/view/:id      <- Path::show_alliance_path($id)
 * /alliances/edit/:id      <- Path::edit_alliance_path($id)
 * /alliances/delete/:id    <- Path::delete_alliance_path($id)
 * </pre>
 *
 * h4. Allgemein:
 *
 * Wenn wir direkt eine Entitaet (ueber eine id gegeben) ansprechen, so
 * muss der controller im Singular sein.
 *
 * <pre>
 * /:controller/:action/:id <- Path::`:action:`_`:controller:`_path($id)
 * `:controller:` muss im Singular sein
 * </pre>
 *
 * Wenn wir ueber alle Entitaeten reden bzw. keine spezifische Entitaet
 * ansprechen, dann muss der controller im Plural stehen.
 *
 * z.B. die Uebersicht von `alliances`
 * <pre>
 * /alliances               <- Path::alliances_path($id)
 * </pre>
 *
 * z.B. Custom Actions, die noch keine Entitaet kennen
 * <pre>
 * /accounts/register       <- Path::register_accounts_path()
 * </pre>
 *
 * z.B. Custom Actions mit ohne spez. Entitaet und named parameters
 * <pre>
 * /accounts/register/confirmation:done   <- Path::register_accounts_path(array('confirmation' => 'done'))
 * </pre>
 *
 * h4. Custom Actions:
 *
 * z.B. `kick` Action in AlliancesController
 * <pre>
 * /alliances/kick/:id      <- Path::kick_alliance_path($id)
 * </pre>
 *
 * oder
 *
 * z.B. `leave` in AlliancesController
 * <pre>
 * /alliances/leave/:id     <- Path::leave_alliance_path($id)
 * </pre>
 *
 * h4. Named Parameters:
 *
 * <pre>
 * /alliances/sort:user_id/order:asc  <- Path::alliances_path(array('sort' => 'user_id', 'order' => 'asc'))
 * /alliances/kick/:id/user:600001    <- Path::kick_alliance_path($id, array('user' => 600001))
 * </pre>
 *
 * @see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#named-parameters
 */
class Path extends Object {

  /** @const */
  const LOGIN_PATH  = '/auth/login';
  const LOGOUT_PATH = '/auth/logout';
  const WELCOME_PATH = '/welcome';

  public static $settings = array(
    'signup' => array(
        'singular' => true,
        'plugin' => false,
        'entityActions' => array('disabled', 'world', 'code_expired', 'confirmation', 'disallowed', 'resend') # must be underscored
      ),
    'recover' => array(
        'singular' => true,
        'plugin' => false,
        'entityActions' => array('account', 'verify', 'token_expired')
      ),
    'support' => array(
        'singular' => true,
        'plugin' => false,
        'entityActions' => array('banned')
      ),
    'contact' => array(
        'singular' => true,
        'plugin' => false
      ),
    'about' => array(
        'singular' => true,
        'plugin' => false
      ),
    'auth' => array(
        'singular' => true,
        'plugin' => false,
        'entityActions' => array('counselor')
      ));



  public static function parseUrl($url) {
    $url = Router::normalize($url);
    $request = new CakeRequest($url, false);

    $params = Router::parse($request->url);
    $request->addParams($params);

    return $request;
  }

  protected static function getId($id){
    // ist kein array, muss id sein
    if(!is_array($id)) {
      return $id;
    }

    // id column vorhanden! als id nehmen
    if(isset($id['id'])) {
      return $id['id'];
    }

    trigger_error('Path: missing id column', E_USER_NOTICE);
    return null;
  }

  /* extract first argument to support:
   * - edit_user_path(1);
   * - edit_user_path(array(1));
   * - edit_user_path(array('id' => 1));
   * url will be /users/edit/1
   *
   * to suport named parameters use second array
   * - edit_user_path(1, array('key' => 'value'))
   * url will result as /users/edit/1/key:value
   */
  /**
   * @param      $args
   * @param bool $requires_id
   *
   * @return array
   */
  protected static function extractOptions($args, $requires_id = false){

    // keine argumente vorhanden
    if(!isset($args[0])) {
      return array();
    }

    // setzen von named parameters
    if($requires_id) {
      $named_parameters = isset($args[1]) && is_array($args[1]) ? $args[1] : array();
    } else {
      $named_parameters = is_array($args[0]) ? $args[0] : array();
    }

    // /alliances/index/name:parameter
    // -> hat keinen index, darum nur die
    // named_paramerters zurueck geben
    if(!$requires_id) {
      return $named_parameters;
    }

    // id muss vorhanden sein!, da kein index
    $id = self::getId($args[0]);
    return array_merge($named_parameters, array($id));
  }

  /**
   * @param $name
   * @param $args
   *
   * @return array|string
   */
  public static function __callStatic($name, $args){
    $parts = explode('_', $name);
    $path_or_url = array_pop($parts);

    # convert path into url
    if($path_or_url === 'url') {
      $name = implode('_', $parts) . '_path';

      # custom paths have priority over general
      $url  = call_user_func_array('static::' . $name, $args);
      return h(Router::url($url, true));
    }

    # neither path nor url
    if($path_or_url !== 'path') {
      return parent::__callStatic($name, $args);
    }

    if(count($parts) == 1) {
      # the short syntax
      $action = 'view';
      $controller_raw = $parts[0];
    } else {
      # first part is always the action
      $action = array_shift($parts);
      # for Path::action_complex_controller_path syntax we have to join
      $controller_raw = implode('_', $parts);
    }

    # underscore controller and action
    $action         = Inflector::underscore($action);
    $controller_raw = Inflector::underscore($controller_raw);

    $settings = isset(static::$settings[$controller_raw]) ?
                      static::$settings[$controller_raw] : array();

    # alias for more descriptive actions
    if($action === 'show') {
      $action = 'view';
    }else if($action === 'new') {
      $action = 'add';
    }

    # if the controller is in singular
    if(isset($settings['singular']) && $settings['singular']) {
      $controller = $controller_raw;
      $no_entity_path = true;
    } else {
      $controller = Inflector::pluralize($controller_raw);
      $no_entity_path = $controller == $controller_raw;
    }

    $is_index_path = $action == 'view' && $no_entity_path;

    # if the controller is in plural, then it is no entitiy
    $is_entity_path = (!$no_entity_path && $action != 'add') || in_array($action, (array)$settings['entityActions']);

    $defaults = array(
      'controller' => $controller,
      'action' => $is_index_path ? 'index' : $action,
      'plugin' => (boolean)$settings['plugin']
    );

    $options = static::extractOptions($args, $is_entity_path);

    return array_merge($defaults, $options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Alt+Enter on the error? In any case: you can lower the severity for that inspection (it has several options) .. or you can even disable that inspection altogether (if so desired).

Comment: Alt+Enter adds the missing function, but I don't need this, as the `Path`-class generates the link via regEx. I also don't want to disable or lower the severity for the `missing function` inspection as I only want to supress it on the `Path`-class but not on other classes. Thanks anyway so far LazyOne

Comment: 1) Show screenshot of your Alt+Enter menu -- you seems may not know what other functionality it has/can do; 2) You can lower severity for cases where such class has magic `__call/__callStatic` methods -- just your case. Have you checked what options that Inspection has .. or this was just "I have not checked but I think..." moment?

Comment: 1) I think you target the "suppress this statement"-option? That's almost what I need but I'd like to have a "global" suppression I could define in the `Path`-class. If this doesn't work I have to spam my code with the "suppress this statement"-option :/ 2) I know that I can lower severity for the magic call methods. But I like to get a warning when a method is not found - except the `Path`-class.

Comment: Excellent -- it's good that you are aware of all those moments (now?). If you were about them before -- you should have mentioned them straight away so I would not had to ask these questions/write them in such manner. **In any case:** This `Path` class of yours -- is this actually yours (I mean -- you can freely modify it) or it is part of some framework which you cannot touch?

Comment: Yes I had mentioned it in a clearer way. The `Path`-class is written by my team, so I can freely modify it.

Comment: Cool. Use `@method` tag in PHPDoc comment for that `Path` class -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#811-method

Comment: I've edited my post to show the results of `@method`

Comment: You want PhpStorm to stop complaining about missing `action_my_controller_path()` method ... then why do you describe `__callStatic()` instead :) ? You should do `@method static string  action_my_controller_path(int $id)` or how ever that method is declared there. **P.S.** Not 100% sure where `static` should go -- before or after return type (`string` in my example above)

Comment: As mentioned in my starting Post the method doesnt exists and will never exists, because the url is dynamicly extracted via `__callStatic()`. I've added the full `Path`-class so you can see what I mean. Also look at the examples in the Comments if you still not understood what I mean with dynamicly extracted.

Comment: **1)** :) This is not *dynamically extracted* method `$this->redirect(Path::action_my_controller_path($id));` -- you are calling `action_my_controller_path()` DIRECTLY. **2)** It does not matter how it will be executed behind-the-scene (dynamically extracted from the name or taken from some map (this name will execute that action etc) .. or even passed to parent class/linked class for execution. It's all about calling it DIRECTLY in your code. And that's what `@method` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want PhpStorm to stop complaining about accessing `action_my_controller_path()` method (or any other **SPECIFIC method**) -- then use `@method` to declare it:

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

**You do not have to declare every single method -- only those that you are planning to call DIRECTLY**, like you did here: `$this->redirect(Path::action_my_controller_path($id));`

---

If you want PhpStorm to stop complaining about accessing **ANY non-existing method**, then you cannot do anything about it -- because you have rejected to use all currently available options for such case:

- **Lowering severity** for accessing non-existing methods **when magic __call/__callStatic are available** .. or completely disable that inspection (last one could be an overkill, I agree);
- **"Suppress for statement"** option to suppress warning in *that particular place*.

Unfortunately there is no `@method` syntax available where you can use wildcards, e.g. `@method static array *(int $id);`.

Comment: If all of your text is emphasised, nothing is.